# Flexible ACL in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, acl

I'm building an application for which I want to use roles managment applicable to individual pages. That is, restrict users' access to pages based on their roles. These roles are stored into the database, as the users. This is the PHP way of doing things and I'm trying to port this to ASP.NET

What I need is that someone can point me to the right resources to look at to acomplish the above task. Until now I have not been able to find what I am looking for.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should checkout the ASP.NET membership provider model:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx3h274z.aspx

Comment: Starting from your source and adding http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html I think I can accomplish what I want, as I'm using an existing MySQL source of users

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for fine grained control then take a look at [Rhino Security](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-security)